# iPhone image won't center

Tags: html, css, iphone, image

Tried to incorporate an iPhone version of a photo to my website, but it is only centered when the iPhone is horizontal. When vertical, the image "zoe-iphone.png" bleeds to the right of the screen. Any way I can adjust this code to center the image? Looks fine on Desktops.

```
<html>
<div class="w3-container w3-center">
   <p>
       <picture>
       
       <div class = "center">
       <source media="(max-width: 790px)"
                srcset="zoe-iphone.png">
        </div>
        
        <source media="(min-width: 791px)"
                srcset="zoe2.jpg">
                
         <img src="zoe2.jpg" max-width="80%" height="400"> 
       
       </picture>
       </p>
</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using flexbox.

```css
center {
  flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
    <main class="center">
        <p>
            <picture>
                <source media="(max-width: 790px)" srcset="zoe-iphone.png">
                <source media="(min-width: 791px)" srcset="zoe2.jpg">
                <img src="zoe2.jpg" max-width="80%" height="400">
            </picture>
        </p>
    </main>
</body>

</html>
```

It also might not be centered because of the margin. Try setting margin to 0 or flexible image size. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_responsive.asp

Edit:
Now it should work

```css
* {
    margin: 0
}

main {
    padding: 1rem;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <picture>
            <source media="(max-width: 790px)" srcset="zoe-iphone.png">
            <img src="zoe2.jpg" width="100%" height="auto">
        </picture>
    </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I tried both and neither worked :/ Could it be the way I'm setting max-width? Because it looks fine when the phone is horizontal

Comment: What's the resolution of your iPhone?